# android api auto startup activity after shutdown and restart

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

i have following problem:

i write broadcastReceiver that receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED all work fine if i do restart from power options or remove battery, but if i use POWER OFF - power option system did't go thrue BOOT_COMPLETED intent. Please help what kind of intent i must receive to get this to cases for auto startup activity on android phone.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".StartupBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Broadcast Receiver class, Check :

> getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
>   // call startActivity(intent);
>   }

It will definitely help you.

Comment: i receive intent, but just if i RESTART phone or remove BATTERY, in other case if i press power button and select from option there "power off" and after that power up the didn't receive. i dodnt know what kind of intent i must use in this case.

Comment: in this case phone may be has to kinds of boot process depend of action restart or shutdown. in second action "shutdown" and afterthat powerup phone didn't fire intent BOOT_COMPLETED